# Coinbase network fees

Tags: gas, wallets, fees

how much are the fees for sending eth from Coinbase? Or what exchange has the lowest fees for sending etherum? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using metamask and possibly uniswap (if you need to convert from another coin into ETH). Coinbase fees can be high and I'm not sure how practical it is to use that wallet as a developer.

I personally mine monero, but unfortunately don't have any ETH right now (Although I have some small amount of BTC and two other coins). I use a hardware wallet for the most part. I do suggest getting a hardware wallet when you can, as leaving the exchanges is probably going to save some money.

Comment: I want to buy some ETH and deposit them into my wallet, and I was wondering if you know any exchange that charges a little amount per transaction? Binance for example charges 17$ worth of network fees and it seems a little too much!

Comment: @Dodo239 According to metamask: A service fee of 0.875% is automatically factored into each quote, which supports ongoing development to make MetaMask even better.